# why is the SOLR _version_ field used by a copyfield?

Tags: solr

I'm running queries on a solr core (solr 8.4) and got some weird results. Checking the schema told me, that the field *version* was set to indexed=false but nevertheless contributed to a copyfield which was defined like this:

```
{ "source":"*", "dest":"_text_"}
```

As far as I understand, *version* is a SOLR-field (so nothing defined by me). But is that an intended behaviour that it ends up in my copyfield? I expected to have solely the content of all the fields, which I defined.